# Simple jquery/javascript dropdown menu with 2 outputs (1 img, 1 title)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dropdown

Please forgive me I'm self-taught with large pockets of knowledge missing ><

I found some code (probably from you guys here at Stockoverflow!) and managed to get it to work in my site. There is only 1 change I need to make to my jquery but it's not working when I do it.

This is the unchanged [version](http://www.tazmaa.com/newpage)
(the dropdown list is what I am working on)

HTML

```
<div class="prints">
    <div><img class="printShop" src="art_images/anime_art_prints/p000a.png" name="image-swap"></div>
    <div><span class="titleName" name="title-swap">Title of Artwork</span></div>
    <div>
        <select name="printchoice" id="printchoice">
            <option data-tname="Select" value="art_images/anime_art_prints/p000a.png">Please Select your Print</option>
            <option data-tname="Selected One" value="art_images/anime_art_prints/p000b.png">A Sassy Catgirl</option>
            <option data-tname="Selected Two" value="art_images/anime_art_prints/p000c.png">Mermaid Friends</option>
            <option data-tname="Selected Three" value="art_images/anime_art_prints/p000d.png">Galaxy Girl</option>
        </select>            
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#printchoice").change(function(){
        $("img[name=image-swap]").attr("src",$(this).val());
    });

    $("#printchoice").change(function(){
        $("span[name=title-swap]").html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

This works how I want it, but it puts the text of the option's value="" into the title span. I want the options `data-tname=""` text to show instead. I tried to replace val() with data('tname') in the second paragraph to no avail. that just seems to break it :(

If it isn't too much of your time, could you take a quick look and see if it is something super simple that I need to change that can make it work how I need it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#printchoice").change(function(){
    $("img[name=image-swap]").attr("src",$(this).val());

    $("span[name=title-swap]").html($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-tname'));
});
```